# spectral profile for multilayer/time series

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, time, multi-band

I am missing a spectral profile in QGIS which enables me to see the values for all bands of a given pixel. (absolutely necessary for multispectral and multitemporal/time series work)

It seems, there has been such a plug in called "earthbeat". http://hub.qgis.org/projects/earthbeat/wiki

This is exactly what I need, but the plugin seems to not work for QGIS 2.2 . It should be in the official repository. Am I getting anything wrong? Thanks for help and clarification.

Comment: Are there any plans to upgrade this important plugin for 2.2 Valmeria? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The last reported version was from July 2012. QGIS plugins are often not *"officially"* maintained, but managed by many volunteers(!), who code the plugins for their own work / projects at a certain time. 
Rather than posting here you might be better off contacting the original plugin author [Bruno Combal](http://hub.qgis.org/users/1206) and ask him directly if he plans to continue developing the plugin.

Also note that the source-code can be cloned and respectively patched directly from the [repository](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/earthbeat/repository). Someone just has to do it ;)

Comment: the last sentence is indeed key :D It would make QGIS so much more powerful. I will have to see when I might be able to have an indepth look at this

Comment: As a plugin author I can tell you that the changes to make plugins compatible between QGIS versions are very subtle. Often you just have to replace some API-calls with others ;) Go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, googling your questions from time to time CAN lead to solutions and answers. For all people out there having the same question: There is a plugin which provides exactly what we are looking for:

Temporal/Spectral Profile Tool 
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/temporalprofiletool/

although it is not possible to collect several points in one layer (and to see the actual points, the profile is located at), it is a nice Plugin